# Rails4 collection_selectのmultipleオプションについて

Tags: ruby-on-rails

問題1
collection_selectにmultiple: trueオプションをつけると
先頭に空文字が入ってしまい値が保存できません

> サーバログ　"brand_id"=>["", "350"],

どうしたら正しく値を保存できるでしょうか

問題2
multiple: trueオプションをつけるとvalidatesで弾かれた場合
値が消えてしまう。

```
<!--  Brand -->
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="brand" class="col-sm-3 control-label">ブランド&ensp;&ensp;&ensp;</label>
        <div class="col-sm-5">
          <%= f.collection_select :brand_id, Brand.where(id: 9..5000), :id, :name_ja, {}, {class: 'form-control multiselect multiselect-primary',multiple: true} %>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

問題１は、`include_hidden: false` を追加すると大丈夫だと思います。

問題２は、brand_id ではなく、brand_idsにすれば解決しないでしょうか？ `multiple: true`なので、複数のidを取得・設定する必要がある気がします。

```
f.collection_select :brand_ids, Brand.where(id: 9..5000), :id, :name_ja, {include_hidden: false}, {class: 'form-control multiselect multiselect-primary',multiple: true}
```

Comment: undefined method `brand_ids' for #<Item:0x007fa2ec4fddc8>となります。
multiple: trueを入れたのは入力によってDBから引っ張ってこれるからです。複数入れる予定は今の所ありません